# Regex printing newlines C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am using Regex to return two lines of text, but it returns newlines with additional text.

```
//Text is located in txt file and contains
I've been meaning to talk with you.
I've been meaning to talk with you.
I've been meaning to talk with you.

string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\...\1.txt");

Regex unit = new Regex(@"(?<Text>.+(\r\n){1}.+)");
MatchCollection mc = unit.Matches(text);
    foreach (Match m in mc)
         foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
              Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
```

[image]

Comment: Please avoid screenshots and use markdown.

Comment: What is the problem here? Note that `.` matches `\r`.

Comment: Well, you have a capture group for a line break (`\r\n`) and you are probably using `ReadLine` which also reads the line break, so basically that group _will_ be captured.

Comment: 1.  Show your input.  2.  The screenshot is perfect and helpful.  3.  You have named capture groups.  Why aren't you using them?

Comment: @Sam Axe Well, you've got me on 3th point. But why is there a newline?

Comment: Are you asking why there is a newline in your groups? Its because you have grouped your newline... I'm not quite sure what you were expecting. If you don't want it captured in a group then you could not put it in brackets (possible because the {1} is redundant). ie you could just use `@"(?<Text>.+\r\n.+)"`. I think you need to go and just read about how regex works, what exactly brackets do and how groups work. As Sam Axe says if you just used your named group you wouldn't even have to worry about what other groups you may be capturing coincidentally...

Comment: Looking for the first match? Use `Regex.Match(text, @".+\r?\n.+").Value`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I want if it is one line grab one line, if it is two lines grab two lines, if it is more then two lines grab only first two lines.

Comment: Ok, you need `Regex.Match(text, @"^.+(?:\n.+)?").Value.Trim()`. If you also want an empty file match, use `@"^.*(?:\n.+)?"`

Comment: Did that work in the end?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew It worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @S.Kablar I added an answer with explanation, please consider accepting/upvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
var m = Regex.Match(text, @"^.+(?:\n.+)?");
if (m.Success) 
{
    Console.Write(m.Value.Trim());
}
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.+` - any 1+ chars other than an LF symbol
- `(?:\n.+)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\n` - a newline
  - `.+` - any 1+ chars other than an LF symbol

The `.Trim()` is used here to trim the result from a possible CR symbol (since in .NET regex, `.` also matches CR symbol.